# Find the number of times a combination occurs in a numpy 2D array

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.6, line-profiler

I have a 2D numpy array, and I want a function operating on col1 and col2 of the array, If 'M' is the number of unique values from col1 and 'N' is the number of unique values from col2, then the output 1D array will have size (M * N) For example, suppose there are 3 unique values in col1: A1, A2 and A3 and 2 unique values in col2: X1 and X2. Then, the possible combinations are:(A1 X1),(A1 X2),(A2 X1),(A2 X2),(A3 X1),(A3 X2). Now I want to find out how many times each combination occurs together in the same row, i.e how many rows are there that contain the combination (A1,X1) and so on.. I want to return the count as a 1D array. This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
#@profile
def myfunc(arr1,arr2):
    unique_arr1 = np.unique(arr1)
    unique_arr2 = np.unique(arr2)
    pdt = len(unique_arr1)*len(unique_arr2)
    count = np.zeros(pdt).astype(int)

## getting the number of possible combinations and storing them in arr1_n and arr2_n
    if ((len(unique_arr2)>0) and (len(unique_arr1)>0)):
        arr1_n = unique_arr1.repeat(len(unique_arr2))
        arr2_n = np.tile(unique_arr2,len(unique_arr1))
## Finding the number of times a particular combination has occured
    for i in np.arange(0,pdt):
        pos1 = np.where(arr1==arr1_n[i])[0]
        pos2 = np.where(arr2==arr2_n[i])[0]
        count[i] = len(np.intersect1d(pos1,pos2))
return count

np.random.seed(1)
myarr = np.random.randint(20,size=(80000,4))
a = myfunc(myarr[:,1],myarr[:,2])
```

The following is the profiling results when i run line_profiler on this code.

Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 18.1849 s
File: testcode3.py
Function: myfunc at line 2

## Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents

```
 2                                           @profile
 3                                           def myfunc(arr1,arr2):
 4         1      74549.0  74549.0      0.4      unique_arr1 = np.unique(arr1)
 5         1      72970.0  72970.0      0.4      unique_arr2 = np.unique(arr2)
 6         1          9.0      9.0      0.0      pdt = len(unique_arr1)*len(unique_arr2)
 7         1         48.0     48.0      0.0      count = np.zeros(pdt).astype(int)
 8                                           
 9         1          5.0      5.0      0.0      if ((len(unique_arr2)>0) and (len(unique_arr1)>0)):
10         1         16.0     16.0      0.0          arr1_n = unique_arr1.repeat(len(unique_arr2))
11         1        105.0    105.0      0.0          arr2_n = np.tile(unique_arr2,len(unique_arr1))
12       401       5200.0     13.0      0.0      for i in np.arange(0,pdt):
13       400    6870931.0  17177.3     37.8          pos1 = np.where(arr1==arr1_n[i])[0]
14       400    6844999.0  17112.5     37.6          pos2 = np.where(arr2==arr2_n[i])[0]
15       400    4316035.0  10790.1     23.7          count[i] = len(np.intersect1d(pos1,pos2))
16         1          4.0      4.0      0.0      return count
```

As you can see, np.where and np.intersect1D take up a lot of time. Can anyone suggest faster methods to do this?
In future I will have to work with real data much larger than this one, hence I need to optimize this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet Bidisha Das requirements:

### Code:

```
def myfunc3(arr1, arr2):

    order_mag = 10**(int(math.log10(np.amax([arr1, arr2]))) + 1)

    #complete_arr = arr1*order_mag + arr2
    complete_arr = np.multiply(arr1, order_mag) + arr2

    unique_elements, counts_elements = np.unique(complete_arr, return_counts=True)

    unique_arr1 = np.unique(arr1)
    unique_arr2 = np.unique(arr2)

    r = np.zeros((len(unique_arr1), len(unique_arr2)))

    for i in range(len(unique_elements)):
        i1 = np.where(unique_arr1==int(unique_elements[i]/order_mag))
        i2 = np.where(unique_arr2==(unique_elements[i]%order_mag))

        r[i1,i2] += counts_elements[i]

    r = r.flatten()

    return r
```

### Test Code:

```
times_f3 = []
times_f1 = []
ns = 8*10**np.linspace(3, 6, 10)

for i in ns:
    np.random.seed(1)
    myarr = np.random.randint(20,size=(int(i),4))

    start1 = time.time()
    a = myfunc3(myarr[:,1],myarr[:,2])
    end1 = time.time() 
    times_f3.append(end1-start1)

    start2 = time.time()
    b = myfunc(myarr[:,1],myarr[:,2])
    end2 = time.time()
    times_f1.append(end2-start2)

    print("N: {:1>d}, myfucn2 time: {:.3f} ms, myfucn time: {:.3f} ms".format(int(i), (end1-start1)*1000.0, (end2-start2)*1000.0))
    print("Equal?: " + str(np.array_equal(a,b)))
```

### Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: I am trying to run your code in the following way:
a = [100,200,100,100,300,200]
b = [1,1,2,1,2,1]
x = myfunc3(a,b)
print(x) outputs [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.] whereas the expected output is [2 1 2 0 0 1]

Comment: Fixed the error in the code: complete_arr = np.multiply(arr1, order_mag) + arr2 instead of complete_arr = arr1*order_mag + arr2

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the maximum possible value of your columns you can use:

```
def myfunc2(arr1,arr2):
    # The *100 depends on your maximum possible value
    complete_arr = myarr[:,1]*100 + myarr[:,2]
    unique_elements, counts_elements = np.unique(complete_arr, return_counts=True)

return counts_elements
```

Results with 8·10e5 and 8·10e6 rows:

```
N: 800000, myfucn2 time: 78.287 ms, myfucn time: 6556.748 ms
Equal?: True
N: 8000000, myfucn2 time: 736.020 ms, myfucn time: 100544.354 ms
Equal?: True
```

Testing code:

```
times_f1 = []
times_f2 = []
ns = 8*10**np.linspace(3, 6, 10)

for i in ns:
    np.random.seed(1)
    myarr = np.random.randint(20,size=(int(i),4))

    start1 = time.time()
    a = myfunc2(myarr[:,1],myarr[:,2])
    end1 = time.time() 
    times_f2.append(end1-start1)

    start2 = time.time()
    b = myfunc(myarr[:,1],myarr[:,2])
    end2 = time.time()
    times_f1.append(end2-start2)

    print("N: {:1>d}, myfucn2 time: {:.3f} ms, myfucn time: {:.3f} ms".format(int(i), (end1-start1)*1000.0, (end2-start2)*1000.0))
    print("Equal?: " + str(np.array_equal(a,b)))
```

The time complexity seems to be O(n) for both cases:

[image: Compute times]

Comment: when finding unique, the complete_arr gets sorted, hence the counts get messed up.

Comment: Also, if a particular combination does'nt occur, I want count[at that position] to be 0, your code does'nt satisfy that

Comment: Busy with something else right now. Will let you know as soon as I try out @Guile Sanchez